# Two related sequences

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, sequence

I want to find the values of this two sequences but I still not able to do that:

[image: click this to see the two sequences]

here is the code of my attempt:

```
from math import sqrt,pi
def a(n,b):
    if n==1:

        return 30
    else:
        return a(n-1)*1.1+(sqrt(2)/(1+pi))*b(n-1)

def  b(n):
    if n == 1:

        return 10
    else:

      return b(n - 1) * 1.1 - (sqrt(2) / (1 + pi)) * a(n - 1)

print(a(2,b))
```

Programming this two sequences in python

Comment: Why did you make `b` an argument to `a`?

Comment: I think there's  a way to defined "b" implicitly in "a"

Comment: _"I still not able to do that"_: What is the problem with your attempy?

Comment: The problem I encountered is that the two sequences are related